# PySpark in Jupyter Notebook: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

I am running an analysis on data about olympic performance and would like to create an overview which athlete has won the most medals. First I create the additional columns since in the original dataset the medal won is indicated by a string ("Gold", "Silver" etc.) or NA.

```
totalDF = olympicDF.count()
medalswonDF = olympicDF\
   .where(col("Medal")!="NA")\
.withColumn("Gold", when(col("Medal")== "Gold",("1")))\
.withColumn("Silver", when(col("Medal")== "Silver",("1")))\
.withColumn("Bronze", when(col("Medal")== "Bronze",("1")))\
.withColumn("Total", when(col("Medal")!=  "NA", ("1"))) -> the  "1" is just a placeholder for now
```

In a next step I would like to display a table for the 25 most successful athletes (in terms of medals won)

```
medalswonDF.cache() # optimization to make the processing faster

medalswonDF.where(col("Medal")!="NA")\
                     .select("Name", "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze")\
                     .groupBy("Name")\
                     .agg(count("Gold")),\
                          (count("Silver")),\
                            (count("Bronze"))\
.orderBy("Gold").desc()\
.select("Name", "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze").show(25,True)
```

However, I keep getting the error "TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable". I understand that this is the case if you want to apply a function that cannot be applied to a column among other reasons but to my understanding this should not be the reason here.

Schema for reference:

```
root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sex: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Height: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Weight: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Team: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NOC: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Games: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Year: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Season: string (nullable = true)
 |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sport: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Medal: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Gold: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Silver: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Bronze: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Total: string (nullable = true)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using extra brackets to close agg before you need to close it.

Change the code as shown below,

```
medalswonDF.where(col("Medal")!="NA")\
                 .select("Name", "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze")\
                 .groupBy("Name")\
                 .agg(count("Gold").alias("Gold_count"),
                      count("Silver").alias("Silver_count"),
                      count("Bronze").alias("Bronze_count")) \
                 .orderBy("Gold_count").desc()\
                 .select("Name", "Gold_count", "Silver_count", "Bronze_count").show(25,True)
```

Comment: thanks, but this results in an exception "cannot resolve '`Gold`' given input columns: [Name, count(Bronze), count(Gold), count(Silver)];;
'Sort ['Gold ASC NULLS FIRST], true". Is this related to the schema or type of values?

Comment: edited the code. can you see whether that works @JackSomeone

Comment: thanks, I finally went with```medalswonDF.where(col("Medal")!="NA")\
                 .select("Name", "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze")\
                 .groupBy("Name")\
                 .agg(count("Gold").alias("Gold_count"),
                      count("Silver").alias("Silver_count"),
                      count("Bronze").alias("Bronze_count")) \
                 .orderBy(col("Gold_count").desc()).show(25,True)```